# C# how to avoid typecasting to subclass?

Tags: c#, .net, subtyping

Let's say I have a base class called Shape. And then some sub classes such as circle and square.

Let's then create a method in another class called GetShape:

```
public Shape GetShape()
{
    return new Circle();  
}
```

Alright, so the idea is, that I can pass in a shapeType and then get a strongly typed Shape subclass returned. The above example is a massive simplification of real code, but I think it gets the point across.

So how when I call this method it would look like

```
var shapeCreator = new ShapeCreator();
Circle myCircle = shapeCreator.GetShape();
```

Only problem is it won't even run, since it requires a cast.

This would actually work:

```
Circle myCircle = (Circle) shapeCreator.GetShape();
```

I'm not wild about that cast, how can I avoid it and still accomplish a way to have a method return a baseclass so that I can return any compatible subclass.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use generics for this, even without reflection. This sample uses the parameterless constructor filter on `T` (sample altered from Adil):

```
public T GetShape<T>() where T : Shape, new()
{
    return new T();
}
```

Comment: @Jodrell: If you don't mind, since you deleted your answer: I added `Shape,` in the filter of `T` from your answer.

Comment: Yes, but what exactly is the advantage of `shapeCreator.GetShape<Circle>()` over `new Circle()` ? And even in the case where it is called from a generic method as `shapeCreator.GetShape<T>()`, how is that better than `new T()` ?

Comment: @Kris: Nothing in its current form, but if there is more generic initialization done from that method, this is a decent solution.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to solve your problem as presented. However, you say

> so the idea is, that I can pass in a shapeType and then get a strongly
>   typed Shape subclass returned

Do you mean something like this:

```
var shape = shapecreator.GetShape(typeof(Circle));
```

or

```
var shape = shapecreator.GetShape<Circle>();
```

If so, and the type is statically known at compile time, just do

```
var circle = shapecreator.GetCircle();
```

If the type is not statically known, but can only be determined at runtime, you will need logic to decide what method to call, e.g. using `if` or `switch` statements. That being said, you need logic like that for a cast as well, so this isn't a real disadvantage.

Another option may be to use an abstract factory design pattern, where you have a `ShapeFactoryBase` class with a `virtual Shape Create()` method, and a derived class `CircleFactory` that inherits from it, and overrides the `Create()` method. You would still need the cast though, and you would still need logic to decide what type to cast to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [generic methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx) to pass the type you want with the method call. In the method you can use [Activator.Createinstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.activator.createinstance) to create the object of type being passed.

*GetShape Definition*

```
public T GetShape<T>() where T : Shape
{
    return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
}
```

*Calling of GetShape*

```
Circle c = GetShape<Circle>();
Rectangle r = GetShape<Rectangle>();
```

**Edit** You can do it without reflection using [new Constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)

> Apply the new constraint to a type parameter when your generic class
>   creates new instances of the type, as shown in the following example:

```
public T GetShape<T>() where T : Shape, new()
{
    return new T();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a function, you could simply nest the shape classes in a `GetShape` static class and create the new shape from that static class as needed.

```
public static class GetShape {
    public class Circle() { .. }
    public class Square() { .. }
    public class Triangle() { .. }
    ...
}


var NewShape = new GetShape.Circle();
```

However, I do recommend the generics exploit if you don't wish to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something `Circle`-specific you must cast to this particular type.

You could use [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) objects but in such case you lose type safty checks on compilation stage.